# Javascript radio buttons - trying to select only checked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write some code which displays certain content only when a combination of radio buttons are checked. Unfortunately, what I've done so far doesn't seem to work - for some reason the content is displaying even when the second radio button hasn't been checked.

Here is my html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SEgraphics.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "form1">
        <input type="radio" name="info1" id="i1" value="1" /><label for = "i1">Item 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="info1" id="i2" value="2" /><label for = "i2">Item 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="info1" id="i3" value="3" /><label for = "i3">Item 3</label>
    </form>
    <form id = "form2">
        <input type="radio" name="info2" id="i4" value="4" /><label for = "i4">Item 4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="info2" id="i5" value="5" /><label for = "i5">Item 5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="info2" id="i6" value="6" /><label for = "i6">Item 6</label>
    </form>    
    <div id ="info1">Test 1</div>
    <div id ="info2">Test 2</div>
    <div id="info3">Test 3</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SEgraphic.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#i1").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        var check1 = $("i4");
        if (check1.checked = true) {
            $('#info3').slideToggle();
        };
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks for your answers everyone - they have been really helpful. I've done quite a bit more on the project now and think I have completed the functionality - it's on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/sim89/pen/BobRxL)

Comment: if (check1.checked == true) {   there should two equal marks

Answer (score 1):

1st you forgot to add **#** to **$("i4")**

2nd use `is(':checked')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#i1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    var check1 = $("#i4");
      if (check1.is(':checked')) {
        $('#info3').slideToggle();
      };
   });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jo42mtLj/1/)

Note: I think you have a lot to do .. So I think it was better to ask your question with everything you want

Update: your code need to simplify like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // top row of buttons //
    // change 'click' to 'change'
    $("input[type='radio']").on("change", function(){
        // remove class clicked from the labels next input in same group
        $(this).parent().find("input[type='radio']").next().removeClass('clicked');
        // add class clicked to the label
        $(this).next().addClass('clicked');
        // hide all the divs its Id starts with info (info1 , info2 ,......)
        $('div[id^="info"]').hide();
        // get info1 checked input value
        var info1_radio = $('input[name="info1"]:checked').val();
        // get info2 checked input value
        var info2_radio = $('input[name="info2"]:checked').val();
        //Make all your if/else statments here to show the div you want
        if(info1_radio == '1' && info2_radio == '4'){
            $('#info1').slideDown();
        }else if(info1_radio == '1' && info2_radio == '5'){
            $('#info2').slideDown();
        }else ......
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/jo42mtLj/6/)

Comment: Thanks - that was really helpful. Here is the full functionality (I hope) on a Codepen [link](http://codepen.io/sim89/pen/BobRxL)

Comment: @sim89 is Codepen works as you want?? or you want modification to it??

Comment: It works as I want I believe - just wanted to let you know it was fixed. It displays information based on the combimation of choices from the two forms.

Comment: @sim89 glad to hear it works .. but your code may need to simplify a lot .. If I got a time I will simplify it to you .. Good Luck

Comment: @sim89 updated answer .. this is how to simplify your code .. make all if/else statements you want .. and please read my comments in code to know what the code doing exactly .. I think it will help you .. Good Luck :)

Comment: That's brilliant thanks - the code is much more streamlined. One thing I don't understand is why .next() removes the 'clicked' class from inputs which are not next in line?

Comment: @sim89 .next() to select the next element .... in your case label is the next element to input .. in my code class clicked is adding to label not input

Answer (score 0):

there are many issues i can see...

1.two equal marks required .

```
if (check1.checked == true) {
```

2.`$("#i4")` instead of `$("i4")`

Please put a jsfiddle and your conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. In the if statement, exra =, so

```
   if (check1.checked == true) {
   $('#info3').slideToggle();
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, you need a # to get it in your javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

$("#i1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    var check1 = $("#i4");
    if (check1.checked = true) {
      $('#info3').slideToggle();
    };
});
```

Why ? because you look for the id i4. In CSS you also call an id with #
Second, you always need two == for if statements (Not for initializing):

```
if (check1.checked == true) {
```

And btw why are you using 2 different Forms ?
And i recommend to download js

Answer (score 0):

Get all checked radios

```
var checkedRadios = $( "input[type=radio]:checked" );
```

Vefify if an element with id="test" is checked

```
if( $( "#test:checked" ).size() > 0 )
```

OR

```
if( $( "#test" ).is( ":checked" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/f9b699yt/) showing one way to do this using jQuery and classes.

HTML:

```
<h1>Check the checkboxes to see more content</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="display-more-cb"/>
<label for="cb1">Checkbox 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="display-more-cb"/>
<label for="cb2">Checkbox 2</label>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">
    <h2>This content is displayed when both checkboxes are checked.</h2>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".display-more-cb").bind("change", function(){
    var allChecked = true;
    var checkboxes = $(".display-more-cb");

    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(!checkboxes[i].checked) {
            allChecked = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    allChecked ? $("#content").show() : $("#content").hide(); 
});
```